# Bulk Insert Data Type Mismatch in datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

In My Bulk Insert Query i have one of the column in .LST file as |12083121022612| Format of this column is as `"YYMMDDHHMMSSTT"` In `dbo.ReportMain` Table i have set Data Type for this as `datetime` 
It gives me error saying that

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 13 (DateAndTime).

Bulk Insert Code:-

```
BULK
INSERT dbo.ReportMain
FROM 'C:\AGS_WINCORE_120901.LST'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `12083121022612` is not a valid date:

```
select cast('12083121022612' as datetime)
-->
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

You could bulk load into a staging table that uses a `varchar` field.  You can convert the `varchar` field to the universal `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:tt` date format.  Here's an example query that could insert rows from the staging table into the main table:

```
insert  ReportMain
        (col1)
select  cast('20' + substring(col1,1,2) + '-' + substring(col1,3,2) + '-' + 
            substring(col1,5,2) + 'T' + substring(col1, 7,2) + ':' + 
            substring(col1, 9,2) + ':' + substring(col1, 11,2) + 
            '.' + substring(col1, 13,2) as datetime)
from    ReportMain_Staging
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/226/0)